# How to resize segmentation mask obtained from Deeplab v3?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation, deeplab

Deeplab v3 returns a reduced/resized image and its corresponding mask. How can I resize the image as well its corresponding mask to better fit to my specification.

Answer (score 11):

cv2.resize method can be used keeping interpolation method to be cv2.INTER_NEAREST

```
resized_image = cv2.resize(segmentation_mask, target_dims, interpolation 
=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

This interpolation method will not lead to change in the RGB values of the labels present in the mask.

If you are saving the masks after resizing, keep the format to be '.png'. Other formats tend to change pixel values by small amount which is not desirable for segmentation masks.